# SQL statement to get column type

Tags: sql, schema

Is there a SQL statement that can return the type of a column in a table?

Comment: Depends on the RDBMS; SQL Server has the `sys.syscolumns` table for example.

Comment: Yes, but it'll be different depending on what type of RDBMS you're using - SQL is a language, not the database product, and this question relies on the specific product. You'll be able to find this sort of information in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table - if your RDBMS has it.

Answer (score 652, accepted):

- In ISO SQL (i.e. *most* RDBMS today) you can use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view, [which SQL Server supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

  - This view's `DATA_TYPE` column contains the T-SQL/SQL Server type names, **except** that it *doesn't* include arguments for parameterised types, which can result in unexpected/unintentional column behaviour.

    - For example, given three columns typed as `nvarchar(max)`, `datetime2(3)`, and `decimal(10,5)` then the output will be `nvarchar`, `datetime2`, and `decimal` respectively.

      - This is a problem because a column typed as `nvarchar` (without `(max)` or `(123)`) [is the same as `nvarchar(1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74484415/159145), and using `decimal` is the same as `decimal(18,0)` *which cannot store non-integer values*.
    - The solution is to *also* look at `CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH` (for `binary`), `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` (for `char` and `nchar`), `DATETIME_PRECISION` (for `datetime2` and `datetimeoffset`), and `NUMERIC_PRECISION` with `NUMERIC_SCALE` (for `decimal` and `numeric`) in order to reconstruct the type's parameter values.

      - Note that `float(n)` can be ignored as SQL Server only supports `float(24)` and `float(53)` which are aliased by `real` and `float` respectively in the `DATA_TYPE` column.

---

```sql
WITH q AS (
    
    SELECT
        c.TABLE_SCHEMA,
        c.TABLE_NAME,
        c.ORDINAL_POSITION,
        c.COLUMN_NAME,
        c.DATA_TYPE,
        CASE
            WHEN c.DATA_TYPE IN ( N'binary', N'varbinary'                    ) THEN ( CASE c.CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH   WHEN -1 THEN N'(max)' ELSE CONCAT( N'(', c.CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH  , N')' ) END )
            WHEN c.DATA_TYPE IN ( N'char', N'varchar', N'nchar', N'nvarchar' ) THEN ( CASE c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH WHEN -1 THEN N'(max)' ELSE CONCAT( N'(', c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, N')' ) END )
            WHEN c.DATA_TYPE IN ( N'datetime2', N'datetimeoffset'            ) THEN CONCAT( N'(', c.DATETIME_PRECISION, N')' )
            WHEN c.DATA_TYPE IN ( N'decimal', N'numeric'                     ) THEN CONCAT( N'(', c.NUMERIC_PRECISION , N',', c.NUMERIC_SCALE, N')' )
        END AS DATA_TYPE_PARAMETER,
        CASE c.IS_NULLABLE
            WHEN N'NO'  THEN N' NOT NULL'
            WHEN N'YES' THEN     N' NULL'
        END AS IS_NULLABLE2
    FROM
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
)
SELECT
    q.TABLE_SCHEMA,
    q.TABLE_NAME,
    q.ORDINAL_POSITION,
    q.COLUMN_NAME,
    CONCAT( q.DATA_TYPE, ISNULL( q.DATA_TYPE_PARAMETER, N'' ), q.IS_NULLABLE2 ) AS FULL_DATA_TYPE

FROM
    q
WHERE
    q.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourSchemaName' AND
    q.TABLE_NAME   = 'yourTableName'  AND 
    q.COLUMN_NAME  = 'yourColumnName'

ORDER BY
    q.TABLE_SCHEMA,
    q.TABLE_NAME,
    q.ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

---

Gives results like this:

[image]

Comment: Only if you don't want to see the corresponding column name.  This will only return the types.  If you want to see the column name the type belongs to you will need to select COLUMN_NAME also...

Comment: And if your table isn't in the default schema you could extend the condition with `AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourSchema'`

Comment: this is great - but is it possible to also have it return the range for column's type? i.e. `varchar(255)` instead of `varchar` and `int(11)` instead of `int` ?

Comment: @mmcrae : It is possible using column  `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. Just do a `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to see all the columns available.

Comment: What about temporary tables?

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman In what context would you need to identify the type of a temp table column?

Comment: It would be useful to see full readable column type like `"numeric(10, 2)"` or `"varchar(100)"`

Comment: You can use this on a view just by using the view name instead of the table name. I almost dismissed this answer for views until I thought of that.

Comment: How to use it in `IF` statement? For example I only want to do some logic if it's an `Integer`?

Comment: @FrancisP I suppose you might if you've created it using the `SELECT ... INTO` syntax and want to check what types SQL Server has decided to use behind the scenes.

Comment: If the DATA_TYPE is set for a particular column in table and we want to get all possible values of that column. SQL statement to get that?

Comment: @PommeDeTerre: This works for me in an IF statement
`IF ((SELECT DATA_TYPE

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

WHERE TABLE_NAME   = N'ACCOUNT' AND COLUMN_NAME  = N'DESCRIPTION') = N'varchar')
BEGIN
     PRINT 'TEST PASS';
END`

Comment: Very useful. Just for beginners, don't forget that it should be single quote. Double quote raised a error for me (I am calling from Rstudio, R 4.1.2, using JDBC and DBI with Postgres driver)

Answer (score 146):

The easiest way in TSQL is:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'yourTableName'
```

Comment: if table is a temporary table or returned by table valued function?

Answer (score 67):

For SQL Server, this system stored procedure will return all table information, including column datatypes:

```
exec sp_help 'YOURTABLENAME'
```

Comment: I upvoted as this is although not exactely the answer but provides valuable information to me. E.g. the "IsComputed" information I didn't find in the Information schema but I can find in the sp_help procedure code and copy from there.

Comment: select table name and click `Alt+F1`.. gives same result.

Comment: to clarifiy: the table or view name has to be selected in the editor and then press`Alt+F1`. Not in the solution Object Explorer. This is such a helpful feature

Comment: And not only tables, also working OK on Views, just:
1. Connect to SQL Server in SSMS
2. Open New Query Window
3. Select your database: use <mydatabase>
4. Run command: exec sp_help <myview>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73442049/3934886 this syntax worked for me >> EXEC [ServerName].[DatabaseName].dbo.sp_help 'TableName'.

Answer (score 29):

If you're using MySQL you could try

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `tbl_name`;
```

[SHOW COLUMNS on dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html)

Otherwise you should be able to do

```
DESCRIBE `tbl_name`;
```

Comment: With *otherwise* you mean other RDBMS apart from MySQL?

Comment: Yes. The `DESCRIBE` syntax is valid in Oracle as well, however MsSQL will not accept this syntax.

Comment: See answer from @jTC for method on MSSQL and TSQL.

Comment: Newer versions of MySQL have `information_schema.COLUMNS`.

Comment: I find DESC OR DESCRIBE (depending on the DBMS you use) useful for small tables with 3 or 4 columns then it shows the table structure with column name Nullable flag and column type for big tables however it take more time to return a result and it is harder to find the information your need.

Answer (score 28):

In TSQL/MSSQL it looks like:

```
SELECT t.name, c.name 
FROM sys.tables t 
JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
JOIN sys.types y ON y.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
WHERE t.name = ''
```

Comment: Actually it is `JOIN sys.types y ON y.user_type_id = c.user_type_id`

system_type_id is not unique. [sys.columns doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 24):

To build on the answers above, it's often useful to get the column data type in the same format that you need to declare columns.

For example, `varchar(50)`, `varchar(max)`, `decimal(p, s)`.

This allows you to do that:

```
SELECT 
  [Name]         = c.[name]
, [Type]         = 
    CASE 
      WHEN tp.[name] IN ('varchar', 'char', 'varbinary') THEN tp.[name] + '(' + IIF(c.max_length = -1, 'max', CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(25))) + ')' 
      WHEN tp.[name] IN ('nvarchar','nchar') THEN tp.[name] + '(' + IIF(c.max_length = -1, 'max', CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(25)))+ ')'      
      WHEN tp.[name] IN ('decimal', 'numeric') THEN tp.[name] + '(' + CAST(c.[precision] AS VARCHAR(25)) + ', ' + CAST(c.[scale] AS VARCHAR(25)) + ')'
      WHEN tp.[name] IN ('datetime2') THEN tp.[name] + '(' + CAST(c.[scale] AS VARCHAR(25)) + ')'
      ELSE tp.[name]
    END
, [RawType]      = tp.[name]
, [MaxLength]    = c.max_length
, [Precision]    = c.[precision]
, [Scale]        = c.scale
, [IsNullable]   = c.is_nullable
FROM sys.tables t 
JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
JOIN sys.types tp ON c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
WHERE s.[name] = 'dbo' AND t.[name] = 'MyTable'
```

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. Thanks, maybe you can add  the condition ( t.type = 'U' )--remove system table

Comment: And VARBINARY types could easily be catered for by adding that to the first `WHEN` line: `WHEN tp.[name] IN ('varchar', 'char', 'varbinary') THEN...`

Comment: The best answer, I would also add: `, [IsNullable] = c.is_nullable` right after `c.scale`. I think it's very useful.

Comment: Added varbinary and isnullable. @Iannick I'm not clear why type = 'U' is necessary? Is it even possible to have a system table with the same name and schema as a user table?

Comment: How would that be changed if I wanted to get something from the owner 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'? `USER_NAME(s.principal_id)` (see [List schema name and owners in sql server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238811/list-schema-name-and-owners-in-sql-server-2012)) does not work for me.

Answer (score 17):

in oracle SQL you would do this:

```
SELECT
    DATA_TYPE
FROM
    all_tab_columns 
WHERE
    table_name = 'TABLE NAME' -- in uppercase
AND column_name = 'COLUMN NAME' -- in uppercase
```

Answer (score 11):

Another variation using MS SQL:

```
SELECT TYPE_NAME(system_type_id) 
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE name = 'column_name'
AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[table_name]');
```

Answer (score 9):

Using TSQL/MSSQL

This query will get you: table name, column name, data type, data type length, and allowable nulls

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name'
```

The only thing that needs to be changed is your_table_name.

Answer (score 9):

This also works as it selects just the column names and their respective character type

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME ,DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Items';
```

Answer (score 7):

To retrieve the actual declared data types, for example for use in dynamic SQL to ALTER COLUMNs, something like this can be used:

```
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME, 
    COLUMN_NAME,
    DATA_TYPE
        + CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('char','nchar','varchar','nvarchar','binary','varbinary')
                    AND CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH > 0 THEN
                 COALESCE('('+CONVERT(varchar,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH)+')','')
            ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('decimal','numeric') THEN
                COALESCE('('+CONVERT(varchar,NUMERIC_PRECISION)+','+CONVERT(varchar,NUMERIC_SCALE)+')','')
            ELSE '' END
        AS Declaration_Type,
    CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE='NO' THEN 'NOT ' ELSE '' END + 'NULL' AS Nullable
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Answer (score 6):

Just if someone finds this useful. In SQL Server:

```
sp_columns 'yourtablename'
```

This will give details of all the columns. It gives you column_name, data_type, type_name, precision, length, iss_nullable, etc.

Mind that the procedure might need more parameters. If you get an empty output, it is likely that you did not enter all that is needed.

Example with more parameters:

```sql
exec sp_columns 'my_table', 'my_owner'
```

SSMS tells you which arguments you can pass to the function while you are writing, just press space after the function command to get a pop up of the parameters:

[image]

Comment: This returns TABLE_QUALIFIER TABLE_OWNER TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE TYPE_NAME PRECISION LENGTH SCALE RADIX NULLABLE REMARKS COLUMN_DEF SQL_DATA_TYPE SQL_DATETIME_SUB CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH ORDINAL_POSITION IS_NULLABLE SS_DATA_TYPE. For an example with screenshots of three stored procedures see [How do I get something like the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS metadata view of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view itself?](https://serverfault.com/a/1155716/607547).

Answer (score 5):

From SQL Server 2012 on:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set( N'SELECT * FROM [my].[Table]', NULL, 0 );
```

Answer (score 4):

```
USE [YourDatabaseName]
GO

SELECT column_name 'Column Name',
data_type 'Data Type'
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'YourTableName'
GO
```

This will return the values Column Name, showing you the names of the columns, and the Data Types of those columns (ints, varchars, etc).

Answer (score 4):

For **IBM DB2** :

```
SELECT TYPENAME FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS WHERE TABSCHEMA='your_schema_name' AND TABNAME='your_table_name' AND COLNAME='your_column_name'
```

Answer (score 4):

Using TSQL/MSSQL

You can use `INTO` keyword.

The result of `SELECT` into a real TABLE

Example: `select .... INTO real_table_name`

After

```
sp_help real_table_name
```

Comment: There is no need to put the view into a table. It also works on views. See the other [later answer which also shows a bit more on the syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73442049/11154841).

Answer (score 4):

Since some people were asking for the precision as well with the data type, I would like to share my script that I have created for such a purpose.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME As 'TableName'
       COLUMN_NAME As 'ColumnName'
       CONCAT(DATA_TYPE, '(', COALESCE(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION, DATETIME_PRECISION, ''), IIF(NUMERIC_SCALE <> 0, CONCAT(', ', NUMERIC_SCALE), ''), ')', IIF(IS_NULLABLE = 'YES', ', null', ', not null')) As 'ColumnType'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE -- ...
ORDER BY 'TableName', 'ColumnName'
```

It's not perfect but it works in most cases.

Using `Sql-Server`

Comment: This answer's query returns incorrect results for `binary` and `varbinary` columns, as they use `CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH` instead of `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH`.

Answer (score 4):

Another option for MS SQL is to replace the `select` query here with the query you want the types for:

```
declare @sql varchar(4000);

set @sql = 'select ''hi'' as greeting';

select * from master.sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set (@sql, Null, 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

use this query

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Answer (score 3):

I find this useful for queries, especially if they use aggregates or several tables (SQL Server)

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = 'select * from yourtable';
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set @query, null, 0;
```

Comment: For an example with screenshots of three stored procedures see [How do I get something like the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS metadata view of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view itself?](https://serverfault.com/a/1155716/607547).

Answer (score 3):

Below SQL script working perfectly at my end.

```
SELECT column_name AS 'Column Name',data_type AS 'Data Type' 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = '[Table Name]'
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest and most useful way in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

```
EXEC [ServerName].[DatabaseName].dbo.sp_help 'TableName'
```

Comment: The syntax does not have to be like this. You can also connect to the db that you need and then run something like `EXEC sp_help 'dbo.TableName'`.

Comment: Same hint is at [SQL statement to get column type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32474909/11154841). For an example with screenshots of three stored procedures see [How do I get something like the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS metadata view of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view itself?](https://serverfault.com/a/1155716/607547).

Answer (score 2):

In my case I needed to get the data type for Dynamic SQL (Shudder!) anyway here is a function that I created that returns the full data type. For example instead of returning 'decimal' it would return DECIMAL(18,4): [dbo.GetLiteralDataType](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31706936/1819403)

Answer (score 2):

Use this query to get Schema, Table, Column,Type, max_length, is_nullable

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(tb.[schema_id])) AS 'Schema'
    ,QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(tb.[OBJECT_ID])) AS 'Table'
    ,C.NAME as 'Column'
    ,T.name AS 'Type'
    ,C.max_length
    ,C.is_nullable
FROM SYS.COLUMNS C INNER JOIN SYS.TABLES tb ON tb.[object_id] = C.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN SYS.TYPES T ON C.system_type_id = T.user_type_id
WHERE tb.[is_ms_shipped] = 0
ORDER BY tb.[Name]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM //table_name// ;
```

It will give you information about all the columns from the table .

Answer (score 1):

For [Spark SQL](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/describe-table.html):

```
DESCRIBE [db_name.]table_name column_name
```

Answer (score 1):

For [Apache Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41774881):

```
select columndatatype from sys.syscolumns
  where referenceid = (
    select tableid from sys.systables
    where tablename = 'YOUR_TABEL_NAME'
    and columnname= 'YOUR_COLUMN_NAME')
```

Answer (score 1):

In vb60 you can do this:

```
Public Cn As ADODB.Connection
'open connection
Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset
 Set Rs = Cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns, Array(Empty, Empty, UCase("Table"), UCase("field")))
```

'and sample (valRs is my function for rs.fields("CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH").value):

```
 RT_Charactar_Maximum_Length = (ValRS(Rs, "CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH"))
        rt_Tipo = (ValRS(Rs, "DATA_TYPE"))
```

Answer (score 1):

simply do this

```
describe table test.oim_test_2
```

you will get details for all your columns with their data types

Answer (score 0):

can use below scrip to gett he same:

```
SELECT column_name 'Column_Name', data_type 'Data_Type' 
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'Name of your desired table'
```

**Note:** *It will not return what size you've specified for varchar/nvarchar type column(s)*

If want to get full details about a table then can use below script:

```
EXEC [Your Database Name].dbo.sp_help 'Your Table Name'
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of to get the data type of columns is:-

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE 'your_table_name';
```

Though it will return the data types of all columns but it gets the job done.

Comment: Can anyone else check this? It does not work for me: `SHOW CREATE TABLE 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS';` throws:
`Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS'.` Ah I get it. This is for MySQL, I was in TSQL.