# Apache Derby error 42802. How can I fix it?

Tags: java, sql, derby

Derby is throwing exception with code 42802. It seems, this particular piece of code is source of trouble, but I can not see why.

```
if(!resultSet.next())
        {
            statement=connection.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"("+
                    "ID varchar(100) primary key,\n"+
                    "TITLE varchar(100),\n"+
                    "AUTHOR varchar(100),\n"+
                    "ISBN varchar(100),\n"+
                    "PUBLISHER varchar(100),\n"+
                    "PUBLISHED_YEAR varchar(100))"
            );
        }
        else
        {
             statement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT INTO BOOKS VALUES ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'));
             statement.execute();
        }
```

Comment: Well you don't have double quotes around your `INSERT` string...that's an obvious problem which would cause a compiler error.

Comment: Sorry, in actual code there are quotes around query, I just tried to provide only the snippet and made typo.

Comment: Check Stephen's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Error 42802 is *"The number of values assigned is not the same as the number of specified or implied columns."*

See https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/ref/rrefexcept71493.html

Now the number of values (6) in your `INSERT` seems to match the number of columns declared by the `CREATE TABLE`.  However, that doesn't mean that the *actual* table structure matches *that* `CREATE TABLE` code.  Check the actual table structure for the `BOOKS` table.

See [how to describe and show table in DERBY DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142624/how-to-describe-and-show-table-in-derby-db)