# List schema name and owners in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, schema

I wanted to list all the table names, column names , schema names and owner in all databases and wrote the code below . I am not sure where to get the schema owners details to add to my query . Please help .

```
select  c.name as colomn_name , t.name as table_name , s.name as schema_name 
 from sys.columns c 
   inner join  sys.tables t     on c.object_id=t.object_id
   INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s  ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The column `principal_id` in `sys.schemas` contains the ID of the schema owner, so to get the name you can simply use:

```
USER_NAME(s.principal_id) AS Schema_Owner
```

Alternatively, if you want more information you can join to sys.sysusers:

```
SELECT  s.Name, u.*
FROM    sys.schemas s
        INNER JOIN sys.sysusers u
            ON u.uid = s.principal_id
```

Comment: Thanks for this . How would I get the table owner ?

Comment: Use the column `principal_id` in `sys.tables`, this is only populated where the owner is different to the schema owner.

Answer (score 18):

Here is a more portable solution that works under SQL Server:

```
SELECT schema_name, schema_owner
FROM information_schema.schemata
```