# How can I view the property of a variable (column) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, types

For example if a column has value like `200806`, and I want to know if this variable is a date variable or a numeric variable or a character variable, where can I see that? Thanks!

Comment: HUH??? You first say you have a column and then say it is a variable. Either way, you look at the datatype of the column or variable to know what datatype it is.

Comment: If you're referring to ta column data type, try this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405572/sql-statement-to-get-column-type

Comment: If you want to actually manipulate the possible data type of value then it is hard to do as "20150702" qualifies both as integer or date.. & of course, it could be string also...
to know the data type from table you can always use **SELECT * FROM Information_Schema.Columns WHERE Table_Name ='your table name'**

Comment: you can use sql_variant_property function to know properties like basetype,precision,scale,totalbytes,collation and maxlength. It is applicable for both variables and Table columns.Check one of my blog post reg it - https://arulmouzhi.wordpress.com/2020/03/01/how-to-know-the-datatype-and-properties-of-a-variable-and-columns-of-a-table/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) then you can expand Database -> Tables -> Columns and find the type of that column.

Else, use `sp_help` (or) `sp_helptext` along with your table name like below

```
sp_help your_table_name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pull the column information for your table by querying the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table:

```
SELECT  DATA_TYPE 
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE   TABLE_CATALOG = 'YourDatabase'
AND     TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YourSchema'
AND     TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable'
AND     COLUMN_NAME = 'YourColumn'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate actual data type from a column by using [TRY_PARSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx)  in SQL Server to test if requested data type is allowable or not ; below is a sample code for that. As you can see that value 200806 is parsed as date

```
SELECT
        TRY_PARSE('200806' AS DECIMAL )  AS 'decimal check',
        TRY_PARSE('200806' AS INTEGER)  AS 'integer Check',
        TRY_PARSE('200806' AS DATE )  AS 'date Check'
```

You might also want to know about TRY_CAST or [TRY_CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) here but they are difference in terms of SQL version and compatibility level [you need to have 110 compatibility to execute that (i.e. SQL Server 2012+)].
Try this

```
SELECT
    TRY_CONVERT(decimal,'200806'  )  AS 'decimal check',
    TRY_CONVERT(INT,'200806' )  AS 'integer Check',
    TRY_CONVERT(DATE,'200806' )  AS 'date Check'
```

If you always consider [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) for gathering metadata information from SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This** @jenny

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'yourTable' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'yourColumn'
```