# Create DataTable Schema from SQL

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, dataadapter

I want to use a dataadapter with a datatable to insert thousands of record into a 30-column sql table.

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataTable table = new DataTable();
adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ...");
adapter.UpdateBatchSize = 1000;
DataRow r = null;
foreach(var entry in list) 
{
    r = table.NewRow();
    r["lastchange"] = entry.TryGet("LastChangeTime"); 
    // <- throws System.ArgumentException: Column does not belong to table
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to not manually define the schema of the datatable, but to read it from the table the insertions should take place in?

Comment: This is possible duplicate of [SQL statement to get column type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405572/sql-statement-to-get-column-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `SelectCommand` and apply `Fill` method to get data first. If you need only table schema just make the query which returns no rows.

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataTable table = new DataTable();
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE 1=2");
adapter.Fill(table);
```

Comment: DO NOT EVER DO THAT. I have seen this in real world and it was terrible performance disaster.

Comment: @MarekVitek, under circiumstances everything can cause a disaster. Can you be more specific, which line is dangerous?

Comment: Dangerous is getting data structure by running query against DB. You might think that your query is simple, then will come someone who thinks why not put it behind view and suddenly you find yourselves running query against view containing multiple joins and few conditions so even simple query will end up doing lot of work.

Comment: There are better ways how to get database structure. As we are not talking specific DB engine, here are few examples [MS SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql) and [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12019.htm) and [PostrgreSQL](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-describe-table/) and [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-information.html) I believe that your trick works just fine most of the time. But it will burn you one day.

Comment: @MarekVitek, Yes, running this against complex view may be costly, but sure it's not OP's case as he says "insert into .. sql table.", and `SqlDataAdapter` implies it's MS sql-server.

Comment: @MarekVitek, Can you specify a better solution please.

Comment: @dellos, I am not C# programmer. But you might want to look at [FillSchema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.fillschema?view=netcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) . I believe it is what you are looking for.

Comment: @MarekVitek, "The FillSchema method retrieves the schema from the data source using the SelectCommand."

Comment: @Serg It may be *more idomatic* to use `FillSchema()`. I agree your method works perfectly fine in most cases. If it doesn't, either you're doing something strange (like targeting a view), the RDBMS is doing something strange, or the DB contention is so high that you should define the table in application logic anyways. The doc says that `FillSchema()` uses `FOR BROWSE`. That has its own caveats, and suggests that it uses `sp_describe_first_result_set` or `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`. One benefit of `FillSchema()` is that the same query for fetching data and schema can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can create/define dataset in your project and can use it in your subsequent operation wherever you need.

Have a look at below link showing how to add dataset to your project and add tables into it and also how to use data adapters with this dataset.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04y282hb.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171919.aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter

I hope this will help you. :)