# How to auto-quote "string values" of a SQL INSERT STATEMENT in Bash script

Tags: sql, arrays, bash, sql-insert, quoting

I have written a simple Bash script that generates a SQL INSERT STATEMENT for multiple rows from CSV data entirely comprised of integers and saves it to a text file (so that I can then copy and paste it wherever I want).

Now I want to know how to *auto-quote* string values; i.e. automatically wrap those columns of the CSV whose data type is string and would need "" in order to be inserted into a SQL table. As you can see below, the script reads the entire CSV row and wouldn't differentiate between columns. Would I have to assign each column to a variable and then quote the string ones separately? Or is there a more efficient way? Either way, I'd be grateful to see your fixes for the above problem!

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Path to to-be-imported CSV:
read csv_file
echo Table name to import into:
read table

echo "INSERT INTO $table VALUES" > SQL_INSERT_$table.txt
while read line
do
 echo "($line),"
done < <(tail -n +2 $csv_file) >> SQL_INSERT_$table.txt && sed -i '' '$ s/.$/;/' SQL_INSERT_$table.txt
```

Comment: which DB are you using ? Perhaps these answers will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405572/sql-statement-to-get-column-type - i.e. the DB knows what type it expects - so you can then tell what to quote..

Comment: Duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66738498/how-to-assign-a-string-column-to-variable-and-have-it-quoted-in-output-in-bash-s

Comment: @MrR: I use MySQL 5.7. I still need to quote the string values in my INSERT STATEMENT, which can be hundreds of rows long. That's why I'm trying to script-quote them and just copy and paste the result into MySQL query box.

Comment: You've got 2 parts to resolve - (a) which columns to quote, and (b) then quote each of the columns .. although doesn't mysql have an importer (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605765/importing-a-csv-into-mysql-via-command-line for some other alternatives).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the modified version of the script above that successfully auto-quotes string columns:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Prompt for input and: 1. enter CSV path to be imported into DB; 2. its equivalent table name in the DB 
echo Path to CSV:
read CSV_file
echo DB table name to import into:
read DB_table

# Create .txt file that will contain SQL INSERT STATEMENT and enter DB table name
echo "INSERT INTO $DB_table VALUES" > SQL_INSERT_$DB_table.txt

# Auto-quote string columns in the .txt file, leaving other columns intact
awk -F, 'OFS=FS {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if (match($i, /^[0-9.-]+$/)==0) {printf "\"" $i "\""} else {printf $i}; if (i<NF) printf OFS}; printf "\n"}' $CSV_file > temp.txt

# read-while loop to populate INSERT STATEMENT row values from CSV (2nd row to the end) and replace final comma with semicolon for those RDBMS's that require a concluding semicolon at the end of SQL STATEMENT
while read line
do
 echo "($line),"
done < <(tail -n +2 temp.txt) >> SQL_INSERT_$DB_table.txt && sed -i '' '$ s/.$/;/' SQL_INSERT_$DB_table.txt

# Delete temporary .txt file that contained auto-quoted string values
rm temp.txt
```

This is a **more complete version** of the script that not only auto-quotes string columns but also *lists out column names into the SQL INSERT STATEMENT*:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Prompt for input and: 1. enter CSV path to be imported into DB; 2. its equivalent table name in the DB 
echo Path to CSV:
read CSV_file
echo DB table name to import into:
read DB_table

# Create .txt file that will contain SQL INSERT STATEMENT and enter DB table name
echo "INSERT INTO $DB_table (" > SQL_INSERT_$DB_table.txt

# List out CSV header as INSERT STATEMENT column names and append to .txt file
echo "`head -n 1 $CSV_file`)" >> SQL_INSERT_$DB_table.txt

# Auto-quote string columns in the .txt file, leaving other columns intact
awk -F, 'OFS=FS {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if (match($i, /^[0-9.-]+$/)==0) {printf "\"" $i "\""} else {printf $i}; if (i<NF) printf OFS}; printf "\n"}' $CSV_file > temp.txt
echo "VALUES" >> SQL_INSERT_$DB_table.txt

# read-while loop to populate INSERT STATEMENT row values from CSV (2nd row to the end) and replace final comma with semicolon for those RDBMS's that require a concluding semicolon at the end of SQL STATEMENT
while read line
do
 echo "($line),"
done < <(tail -n +2 temp.txt) >> SQL_INSERT_$DB_table.txt && sed -i '' '$ s/.$/;/' SQL_INSERT_$DB_table.txt

# Delete temporary .txt file that contained auto-quoted string values
rm temp.txt
```