# NVARCHAR variable not working in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, declare, nvarchar

In SQL Server (2018 I think? I don't know how to tell) my variable isn't working in `WHERE` clauses for `NVARCHAR.` The comparison should return values but it returns nothing. If I just type the declared text in manually it suddenly works and returns values. There's no logical reason this should be any different, the types are both NVARCHARS. It is working for dates and numbers for me.

The following SQL Server code works properly and returns results:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column = 'text'
```

The following code fails however by coming up empty when I use an initial declare statement:

```
DECLARE @Class AS NVARCHAR = 'text'

SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column = @Class
```

I can't get the variable to work in the `WHERE` clause even though I have confirmed that column is an `NVARCHAR`. Other parameters I'm declaring work just fine it just seems to be `NVARCHAR` giving me issues.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Try to reproduce this issue in a DBFiddle or SQLFiddle and post the link here.

Comment: BTW, `'text'` is a `varchar` literal, while `N'text` is an `nvarchar` literal.

Comment: `select @@version` to get the version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not do what you think it does:

```
DECLARE @Class AS NVARCHAR = 'text';
```

- You **must** specify the length parameter `n` with `varchar(n)`, `nvarchar(n)`, and `varbinary(n)` column types, because if you don't it's equivalent to `n = 1`.
- So `DECLARE @Class AS NVARCHAR = 'text'` is the same as:

  - `DECLARE @Class AS nvarchar(1) = 'text'`
  - Which means `@class = N't'` and not `N'text'` (but it would be if you put `DECLARE @Class AS nvarchar(4)`.

You can see it by running this:

```
DECLARE @Class AS NVARCHAR = 'text'
SELECT @class;
```

...which gives you `t` as output:

[image]

---

Therefore, change your SQL to this:

```
DECLARE @class nvarchar(4) = N'text';

SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column = @class;
```

Also, don't forget to always schema-qualify your object-names: i.e. prefer `dbo.table` to just `table`.

Comment: Thanks that worked, it was a simple issue but I couldn't manage to google the right thing

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the length of `nvarchar`. For example:

```
DECLARE @Class AS NVARCHAR(10) = 'text'
```

You can check the value of `@Class` by running 'select @Class' to see what it contains.

Comment: Please clarify how this is an improvement over the existing answer which explains this and more?

Comment: Hi Dale at the time i started the post your answer wasn't there :)  Your response is more thorough i would agree.  Have a little patience with newbies :)  Seems a little tense here.

Comment: Don't forget to prefix your `NVARCHAR` literal value with `N` (e.g. `N'text'`).

Comment: Appreciate the shorter explanation fix too thanks

Comment: Thanks:). My first post in stack overflow :).